# UK Visa Supporting Documents for Employer Sponsorship

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel, spouses

I was invited to the UK for training and my employer has generously sponsored everything for me and my spouse. I already have the invitation letter.

My husband will not be attending the training BUT his sole purpose is to accompany me. We'll basically have the same itinerary. I don't think they'll mind having him around since he's also involved in the business somewhat and it will be informal in nature.

1. What are the other necessary documents to include in our application to show financial evidence that they can support us? Or is the letter of invitation enough?
2. Will they expect us to have money in the bank even if the company is paying for everything? If yes how much?
3. In the online application both of us have selected 'business'. Would that apply to my spouse too?

Comment: My husband will not be attending the training BUT his sole purpose is to accompany me. We'll basically have the same itinerary. I don't think they'll mind having him around since he's also involved in the business somewhat and it will be informal in nature. Do you think we should change his visa type to tourist?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the extra information from your comment

Comment: Please split this into three separate questions. Thank you.

Comment: we just got approved today :) thank you for the help..

Comment: to help others, here's what i did for my concerns above. #1 we did not provide any document but the company was able to include a business number in the invitation letter that the immigration officers can check. #2 because we have no savings for this trip, we borrowed money from my father, asked my father to write a letter stating borrowed money. we then provided bank statements (to show movement of money) #3 my application was visit-business and my spouse application was visit-tourist